# Equivalent of nvtop (NVIDIA graphics cards) for AMD graphics card on MacOS Big Sur 11.1

Tags: top, macos, gpu, amd-graphics

I have a AMD Radeon Pro 5600M 8 Go graphic card on my MacBook pro 16" and I would like to know if there exists a tool like `nvtop` for AMD cards on MacOS Big Sur : this would be for seeing the ressources taken by the GPU in live when I make run big simulations.

I did some reasearches but couln't have found a `brew` package or `macport` package, neither via `pip3` python package.

If someone knew if this kind of tool exists, this would be fine to tell it.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: December, 2023: `nvtop` now supports AMD!  I've tried several different options and nvtop is by far my preference:  https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop

Previous answer for posterity:

I haven't been able to find anything like `nvtop` for AMD, but there is a project called `radeontop` that is better than nothing:  https://github.com/clbr/radeontop

The worst part is that I can never remember the name when I need to run it.  I finally aliased it in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias amdtop='radeontop'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the github page for nvtop, it supports AMD along with Intel too.

https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop#amd

I guess originally it was written with nVidia in mind, hence it's name, but now the nv stands for 'neat videocard'.